# .htaccess RewriteCond exclude frontpage

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how i may able to turn on https to all pages but not frontpage via .htaccess anyone can help me with the rewritecond please.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR] 
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]


  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I already have this, and my goal is to EXCLUDE FRONTPAGE for HTTPS, only inner/subpages should have HTTPS.

Please help me modify my existing one please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
 RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]

 # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`.+` instead of `.*` makes sure http is enforced for other sub pages except front pages.

Comment: thank you, how is it possible if someone access https://mydomain.com or https://www.mydomain.com it will change it to http://, if someone access frontpage with https:// it will force to http:// only frontpage, the rest should retain its https://

Comment: yes sure that can be done. Added that rule in my updated answer.